# Git shows two branches in remote

Tags: git

I cloned a git repo and created a branch A using git checkout -b A . After that I did some changes and committed in branch A and pushed it to the remote branch using

```
    git push -u origin/A
```

Meanwhile,I have deleted my local workarea . Now I have to make changes in A. So I cloned the repo again. Now I have two branches origin/A and A . 
Should I do

```
     git checkout A 
       (or)
     git checkout -b branchname origin/A
```

Question:
   1) why two branches of the same name when both are same?

Answer (score 1):

origin/A is the remote, A is your local, so they can be different if remote or local is not up to date. But you do not need to clone again to get a branch, you just have to do `git fetch --all`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word *branch* is poorly chosen here. You might say it is a *reference point*: it is a reference to a commit in the commit graph.

The reason is that `git` is **distributed**: every peer stores a (part) of the commit graph. There is no guarantee that the graph on your machine is exactly the same as the one on the remote machine (`origin`), or on the machine of a friend that collaborates on the project as well.

It is for instance possible that the local graph looks like:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \      \
              \      \
A              def----jkl
```

That means that there are two pointers `master` pointing to `mno` and `A` pointing to `jkl`. Now the remote can not have been updated recently and only contain:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \
              \
A              def
```

It is also possible that another developer made contribution `xyz` in the remote resulting in a graph:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \
              \
A              def---xyz
```

In that case the union looks like:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \      \
              \      \
A              def----jkl
                  \
                   \
origin/A            xyz
```

In that case `origin/A` points to `def` and `A` points to `jkl`.

So both are the *same* if the remote is completely in sync with the local repository.

A *`git checkout`* means you are setting the *active branch*, it means that active state of the project now switches to where the reference is pointing to. If you thus do `checkout A`, the system will modify files such that it looks like the state stored in commit `jkl`, furthermore `jkl` will be marked as the "current" state.

If you would run `git checkout -b B A` (mind, not `origin/A`). You simply create a new branch. From now on, both `A` and `B` point to `jkl`. Thus:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \      \
              \      \
               def----jkl
                     / |
                   <A> |
                       /
                    <B>
```

If you run `git checkout -b B A`: and as said before the `origin` is not fully synchronized (or is synchronized further), it will result in:

```
master    abc----ghi---mno
             \      \
              \      \
               def----jkl
              /      /
           <B>    <A>
```

You can run `git fetch --all` or `git pull --all origin` to synchronize the graphs.